# Compiler error for nested class with override func - Swift Xcode6

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have a simple Cocoa Touch Framework project with Swift code only. In my unit test class I want to do mocking so I created a mock class which inherits from the type I want to mock:

```
func testFirstClassMocking() {
    class MockSecondClass: SecondClass {
        var mockedResult = "My mocked value"
        override func printSecondLogEntry(logEntry: String) -> String {

            return mockedResult
        }
    }

    let mock = MockSecondClass()

    var firstClass = FirstClass(secondClass: mock)

    let result = firstClass.printFirstLogEntry("whatever")

    XCTAssertEqual("My mocked value", result);
}
```

This result in a generic compiler error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Now, when I take the nested class out of the function and nest just in my testing class - everything is great. Code compiles and my unit test runs great. Is class nesting in functions not allowed any more?

My Xcode ver: Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

EDIT: one other thing - if I remove the override of the func - the compiler has no issues. Obviously I need the override func to be able to return a value I need in my unit test when my mock object runs.

Comment: I didn't realize you could nest a type inside another type's method. Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you might want to know that the following 'mock' of your mock test is compiling and passing. Let me know if I missed something about your code **as it is in your question**. If I did not miss anything, however, then the cause of the error is something about your code **that did not make into the question**. Hope that helps you either find the culprit or reformulate the question:

```
import XCTest

class FirstClass {

    let secondClass: SecondClass

    init(secondClass: SecondClass) {
        self.secondClass = secondClass
    }

    func printFirstLogEntry(entry: String) -> String {
        var fullLog = self.secondClass.printSecondLogEntry(entry)
        return fullLog
    }
}
class SecondClass {

    func printSecondLogEntry(logEntry: String) -> String {
        return logEntry
    }
}

class CommandLineTests: XCTestCase {

    func testFirstClassMocking() {
        class MockSecondClass: SecondClass {
            override func printSecondLogEntry(logEntry: String) -> String {
                return logEntry
            }
        }

        let mock = MockSecondClass()

        var firstClass = FirstClass(secondClass: mock)

        let result = firstClass.printFirstLogEntry("whatever")

        XCTAssertEqual("whatever", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Milos, My code is the same with 2 exception:

1. FirstClass and SecondClass types are in a different target (which I don’t think matters that much)
2. The func in FirstClass uses the func from SecondClass (hence the need for mocking). So:

    func printFirstLogEntry(entry: String) -> String {
        var fullLog = self.secondClass.printSecondLogEntry(entry);
    
        return fullLog
    }

Can you try it and see what you get? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code that passes the test. Have a look and let me know if you'd like me to try something else... I'm running this on Xcode 6.1 GM seed for OS X Yosemite